# Rails Impressionist Gem - WillPaginate::Collection is not impressionable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, impressionist

There is any way to use impressionist gem with will paginate? I try to use impressionist to a `will_paginate` collection like this:

```
posts = Post.all.paginate(:page => params[:page]) 
impressionist(posts)
```

But It raises this error:

```
WillPaginate::Collection is not impressionable!
```

There is any way to use impressionist method directly on view?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share your code. What was the issue?

Comment: Hello spickermann, thank you very much for your answer. I paginate a result like this:
posts = Post.all.paginate(:page => params[:page]) and then I try to use impressionist gem on posts with the method:
impressionist(posts) but I get this error:
WillPaginate::Collection is not impressionable!
How can I use impressionst gem with a WillPaginate:Collection?
Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2):

The collection generated by `will_paginate` is not impressionable means exactly you are reading, it's class doesn't have any calls to `is_impressionable`, as your model should have. If it doesn't, add it like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ...other stuff
    is_impressionable
end
```

Then, if you can't call it in the collection, why not call it in each record instead? Try like this:

```
posts = Post.all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
posts.each{|post| impressionist(post) }
```

Maybe it's not the most elegant solution, but it will get the work done. As of doing this in your view, I wouldn't advise it. Impressionist creates a database record, which would slow your view rendering. It will be better to do it in the model or controller layers.